How to route around a passthrough switch
I'm not experienced with networks, so please be patient if I use incorrect terminology. I tried to google, but due to the lack of words to exactly describe my problems I didn't find anything useful.
I have the following setup:
       / -- PC1                                 /--  PC 2
Router - POE Switch <-> POE Passthrough Switch ---  Device 2
       \ -- Device 1                            \--  Wifi Repeater

*"Router" is a Fritzbox 5590
*"POE Switch" is a "TP-Link TL-SG1005P PoE Switch 5-Port" which injects POE and sounds like a "normal" switch
*"POE Passthrough Switch" is a POE Powered POE Extender sold as a "MokerLink Outdoor 5 Port PoE Extender, IEEE 802.3 af/at/bt PoE Repeater 90W, 10/100Mbps, 1 PoE in 4 PoE Out, Wall Mount Waterproof POE Passthrough Switch"
*"Wifi Repeater" is a "FRITZ!Repeater 1200 AX"
The problem now is, that I can't reach Device 2 from PC2, and I can't reach any other Device that is connected to my wifi via the WIFI-Repeater from PC2. I can reach PC1 and Device1 from PC2. I assumed, that the "POE Passthrough Switch" would act as a normal switch, connecting all the ports with each other, but it seems that only the POE Input Port is connected to the other ports.
Is there a way to configure my network so that PC2 uses the Router to speak to device 2? If so, what would be good keywords to start googling?

Ok, the problem was solved - it's not a bug, it's a feature. After posting, I was thinking about writing a review on amazon for the POE Passthrough switch, mentioning the problem, that it's not a full switch.
I found a review there, that solved the problem: There is a switch on the device labeld On/Off, and I put it to On before plugging my cables in.
Fun fact: It's not an On/Off-Switch for the device, but for a V-LAN feature that allows to separate the different channels - it's just not labeled properly.
I might or might not have read the f... manual.
